# Does analyst API Flurry break Australian Privacy Act or any other Legal, Regulations, Compliance?

Tags: mobile, legal, cissp

I want introduce Flurry API in my iOS app. But I heard since 2014 Australia start an act to against web page and mobile app to collect user information.

My question is simple: 
Does using of API Flurry break Australian law? or any kind of regulations?

P.S.
IN CISSP, Law and regulation is part of Information Security. That is reason I post my question here. Thank you.

Comment: The Australian signals directorate seems to think it's fine to just collect everything on anyone. So it must be ok. A government agency wouldn't violate the law, right?

Comment: @ashamed_aussie But all of those information will transport to Flurry's US Server. Is this fine for us? If their data centres sit in China or Russia, is this still OK for us?